# Linear Algebra: Cross Product w/ Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, cross-product

> Let v = $\begin{bmatrix}
>     v_1\\
>     v_2 \\
>     v_3 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$. Which matrix A implements the transformation:
>   
>   $x = \begin{bmatrix}
>     x_1\\
>     x_2 \\
>     x_3 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$ $\rightarrow $ $v\times x = \begin{bmatrix}
>     v_2x_3 - v_3x_2\\
>     v_3x_1 - v_1x_3 \\
>     v_1x_2 - v_2x_1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$

So I've been thinking about this geometrically, and can't really wrap my head around it: is it just the 3x3 identity matrix? This would prove to be a perpendicular matrix to any two given vectors. Nevertheless, the question itself confuses me: how does a matrix itself implement a cross product? Does it mean to just give an example of a matrix that serves as an intermediary to give the answer?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

It's the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-v_3&v_2\\v_3&0&-v_1\\-v_2&v_1&0\end{bmatrix},$$as you can check.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}\,0&\!-a_3&\,\,a_2\\ \,\,a_3&0&\!-a_1\\-a_2&\,\,a_1&\,0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ implements the cross product of a *fixed* vector $v$ with a *variable* vector $x$. You’ve already got a formula for this cross product in the question itself. Simple extract the coefficients on the right-hand side into a matrix.